# How to compute unpolarized cross section for $e^−+\gamma \to e^−+\pi$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

I need some help with this calculation. I have already made a few attempts but, even applying Feynman's rules for QED on the first vertex and for Yukawa interaction on the second one, I cannot figure out the various indexes.

The full calculation is not needed. I just need to have the correct setting of the reduce matrix amplitude.

Thank you so much!

**Lagrangian:**

$\mathscr{L} = -\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi -\frac{1}{2}m_\pi^2\phi^2 + \bar{\psi}(i\gamma^\mu \mathscr{D}_\mu - m_e + \lambda\phi)\psi - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \mathscr{L}_{gauge-fixing}$

**Feynman rules found:**

$\mathscr{L}_{Yukawa} = \lambda\phi\bar{\psi}\psi$

from 3-point correlation function

$G^{(3)}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{1}{Z[0,0,0]}{\displaystyle \int}\mathcal{D}\phi\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi \ e^{iS_0[\phi,\bar{\psi},\psi]} \ \phi(x_1)\bar{\psi}(x_2)\psi(x_3) \ \left[1 + i\lambda{\displaystyle \int}dy \ \phi(y)\bar{\psi}(y)\phi(y) \right]$

using Wick and LSZ, the rules are:

- $i\lambda$ for each vertex;
- $\frac{i}{p^2 - m_\pi^2}$ for each $\pi$ propagator;
- $\frac{i}{\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m}$ for each $e$ propagator;
- $u_s$ for each incoming electron;
- $\bar{v_s}$ for each incoming positron;
- $\bar{u_s}$ for each outgoing electron;
- $v_s$ for each outgoing positron.

$\mathscr{L}_{QED} = -ie\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\mathcal{A}_\mu\psi$

after similar steps:

- $-ie\gamma^\mu$ for each vertex;
- $\frac{-i\eta_{\mu\nu}}{p^2}$ for each e.m. propagator;
- $\frac{i}{\gamma^\mu p_\mu - m}$ for each $e$ propagator;
- $u_s$ for each incoming electron;
- $\bar{v_s}$ for each incoming positron;
- $\epsilon_\mu^*$ for each incoming photon;
- $\bar{u_s}$ for each outgoing electron;
- $v_s$ for each outgoing positron;
- $\epsilon_\mu$ for each outgoing photon.

**The question is:**

How can I put all this together to correctly calculate the amplitude for the scattering $e^−+\gamma \to e^−+\pi$?

Comment: You haven't shown us any of your work, you should include all of your attempt otherwise we can't accurately determine the issues.

Comment: There is an effective πγγ coupling due to the ("safe") anomaly that underlies neutral pion decay, as you must have covered in your particle physics course. I gather you need not compute this anomaly from first principles anymore, but just use the vertex calculated. So you have a tree diagram of a propagating electron emitting a γ which joins the incoming γ to produce a π. This is the trail map.  The Lagrangian you have, with the phony Yukawa looks suspect.

Comment: The lagrangian is a poor parity-violating bluff. I hope your instructor has not given this to you. The gauge-fixing piece is a pointless non-sequitur for QED. The vertex you are missing from your effective lagrangian is the $\tilde{F}F\pi^0$ parity preserving term....

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Yes, this Lagrangian is a bit problematic but it is just an exercise to practice Feynman's Rules and the calculation of the cross section.
As soon as possible I will add what I found and the precise point where I am stuck.

Comment: As you wish; one can't argue with a finger exercise. You might insert a $\gamma _5$ in your Yukawa to preserve parity, and pretend the electron emits two virtual photons converting to a real neutral pion through the above anomaly, but this is quite subleading to the actual amplitude.